# Find the inverse using fast exponential algorithm or Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, cryptography

How to find the inverse of

> 35<sup>721</sup> mod 1823

which one should do first fast exponential algorithm or Extended Euclidean Algorithm??

How do get started??

Which value should use for fast exponential algorithm or Extended Euclidean Algorithm

No calculator allow

Comment: Personally, I'd used both.  First find the inverse of $35$ with EEA, then exponentiate.

Comment: how you use exponential

Comment: Fast exponentiation, as you said.

Comment: Note that $35^{721} = 35^{512+128+64+16+1} = 35^{512} 35^{128} 35^{64} 35^{16} 35$.You find all of these values by repeatedly squaring $35 \mod 1823$

Comment: than use Extended Euclidean Algorithm to inverse??

Comment: Since $1823$ is prime, the inverse of $35^{721}$ is $35^{1101}$.